# SVN server communication details for VDFS repository replication

Tags: svn, visualsvn-server

there are two SVN server S1 and S2, I want to create replication between them, what will be the details like

1. Firewall settings(need to enable or disable the settings)
2. Port number(need to open any port for communication)

and other details which will be required for both servers to communicate.

Thanks in advance.

Please reply as soon as possible.

Comment: Welcome to stackoveflow. Please add something that you have already tried so that the community can help you.

Answer (score 0):

- [VDFS services use the TCP port 8337 to communicate with each other](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00073/).
- There is a predefined firewall rule named VisualSVN Distributed File System Service that allows remote slave VDFS services to communicate with the local VDFS service. The rule is created during the VisualSVN Server installation but not enabled by default. You need to [enable this rule on master server](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00073/).

For other information about setting up VDFS read the article [KB136: Getting started with Multisite Repository Replication](http://%20https://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00136/).